# How to add custom attributes to asp.net dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a country name as country attribute to asp.net dropdown list control but i am not having any luck with it.

```
ListItem newState;
foreach (DataRow drow in dsDist.Tables(1).Rows)
{
    newState = new ListItem(drow("statename").ToString(), drow("state").ToString());
    newState.Attributes.Add("country", drow("country-name").ToString());
    ddlstates.Items.Add(newState);
}

ddlstates.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
ddlstates.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

**After Page Render;**

```
<select name="ddlStates" id="ddlStates" class="chosen-select-states" data-placeholder="search by state name" style="display: none;">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

**This is what i am expecting;**

```
<option country="usa" value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option country="canada" value="ON">Ontario</option>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this attribute ? Do you want it to be visible in the list items ?

Comment: yes. i have updated my question with what i am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes should be visible on the rendered page with your browser's developer tools. But, attributes won't be posted back and you won't be able to get them back on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for example.

You have to create your own custom control derived from DropDownList or to store those attributes elsewhere.

Depending on what you want to do, you could perhaps store a `Dictionary<String,String> itemAttributes` containing ListItems values and attributes.

This could something as :

```
Dictionary<string, string> itemAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            ListItem newState;

            foreach (DataRow drow in dsDist.Tables(1).Rows)
            {
                newState = new ListItem(drow("statename").ToString(), drow("state").ToString());
                //newState.Attributes.Add("country", drow("country-name").ToString());

                ddlstates.Items.Add(newState);
                itemAttributes.Add(drow("state"), drow("country-name"));
            }

            ddlstates.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
            ddlstates.SelectedIndex = 0;

            Session["Attributes"] = itemAttributes;
            ViewState["Attributes"] = itemAttributes;
```

Beware of the size of the session or viewstate if you use this method.